# Most efficient way to convert a Date String to another date String without using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I want to convert one Date String to another Date String.

For example i get an input date as `"31-10-2018"` and I want to convert it to `"2018-10-31"`.

I already have the information regarding the **input pattern** in which I am receiving the 
date i.e "dd-MM-yyyy".

Also the output pattern in which i need the output date string i.e **"yyyy-MM-dd"**.

But the condition is that i don't want to use **`SimpleDateFormat`** and also don't want to use `parse()` or Format method of SimpleDateFormat.

As stated previously I am getting the input in form of string and also need the output in the form of String only.

What could be the most effiecint way of achieving this ?

I want to add a few things about the question :-

1. I know java's SimpleDateFormat is sufficient in terms of performance but i don't want to use it since it requires creating number of additional objects which I don't want since i have an input date in form of String which i want to convert into another String.
2. My input and output formats can be different but i get them as input to my method. say:-

```
public String getOutputString(String inputString, String inputPattern, String outputPattern) {
     // logic to get the output string 
}
```

Comment: Use `java.time`, it's really good, modern and even short in most cases.

Comment: *most effiecint way* in what? Memory usage, CPU usage, lines of code, ....?

Comment: Do you actually have evidence that `SimpleDateFormat` is not sufficiently performant?

Comment: "condition is that i don't want to use SimpleDateFormat" can you provide reasoning for that (I am assuming this also includes `java.time` package)? For now it looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: @Jens in term of execution time.

Comment: @AndyTurner I never said that it is not good at performance. I am just looking for more efficient ways if there are available any.

Comment: @RahulSharma what distinction are you drawing between performance and efficiency?

Comment: @AndyTurner using simpledate format will require to create two SimpleDateFormat Objects. then calling outputformat.format(inputfomat.parse(inputString)), which internally first creates a new Date object and again converts that into a String as output. I was hoping if there a more efficient way to achieving this when all i have is an input string which i want to convert to another string.

Comment: @RahulSharma but have you actually found evidence that creating those objects matters to the code's performance? The JIT may mean those objects never actually get created; or some other bit of your code is wildly inefficient, and so swamps any performance gains.

Comment: could the output pattern be funky stuff like `"yy-MMM-dd"` or is it always date on 4 digits, month on 2 and day on 2?

Comment: Don’t be concerned with execution time. Unless you have millions of strings to convert, no one will be able to judge whether the conversion takes a few microseconds longer or shorter. And in any case avoid `SimpleDateFormat`, it’s notoriously troublesome and long outdated. It all boils down to using [the answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59770037/5772882).

Comment: @OleV.V. actually i do have millions of Strings to convert that's why it matters. Even if i could save few seconds, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

## Easiest (and nowadays recommended) way: `java.time`

It is *the most efficient way* in terms of readability and shortness of code, but won't have significant influence on execution time or allocated memory.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("31-10-2018",
                                            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    System.out.println(localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
}
```

Output: `2018-10-31`

This way, you won't need `SimpleDateFormat` or any class from `java.util`!

**EDIT**
To pick up the unimplemented method you subsequently added to your question, this would be its implementation using the way shown above:

```
public String getOutputString(String inputString, String inputPattern, String outputPattern) {
     return LocalDate.parse(inputString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(inputPattern))
             .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outputPattern));
}
```

Comment: @Jens I think this answer is correct, and it answer multiple problems, what is the input of the OP look like `32-10-2018`, yes it respect the date but it doesn't a correct date

Comment: @YCF_L So you think that is the **most**  effiecint way?

Comment: @Jens it is **not** the most efficient way in terms of performance (as edited), but it is an efficient way in several other terms of quality. The answer was posted **before** OP clarified his interpretation of *efficiency*.

Comment: @Jens we have to know first, what is this question for, for formatting date or formatting strings?

Comment: @deHaar Thanks. I found it fairly effective to use java.time. On 10M rows on my machine on average it took 2.5 seconds less than using SimpleDateFormat. It might vary for different people but for me at least, it was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Munging dates without a proper date/time library is a fool's errand.

With that said, you can turn a string `31-10-2018` into `2018-10-31` like so:

```
String s = "31-10-2018";
String t = new StringBuilder(10).append(s, 6, 10).append('-')
                                .append(s, 3, 5).append('-')
                                .append(s, 0, 2).toString();
```

I simply wouldn't advise it.

Comment: You'd also need to be sure single digit numbers are 0-padded, this code would fail for "1-1-2020".

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: OP changed his question, following answer is not valid anymore** Only works to change from "dd-MM-yyyy" to "yyyy-MM-dd"

Split on `-`, reverse the list, and re-join with `-`

```
List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList("31-10-2018".split("-"));
Collections.reverse(tokens);
String reversedDate = String.join("-", tokens);
```

Comment: It doesnt work for configurable pattern as OP question mentioned after edit